# How to read C header # define by powershell

Tags: powershell, teamcity, version

I need to set up per branch versioning schema for Continuous Integration in TeamCity. The last part of what I need to do is the Powershell script to parse the version from C++ header file.

I do it in following steps

I have following C++ header file

```
#ifndef VERSION_H
#define VERSION_H

#define VERSION 4.0.1
#define BUILD_NUMBER 9999    

//git SHA
#define GIT_SHA NotCommittedChanges

#endif //VERSION_H
```

And Powershell script which should read VERSION and set up a

```
$content = Get-Content version.h
$version = ParseDefine('VERSION', $content)
$buildNumber =[string]::Concat($version, ".", '%build.number%')    
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$buildNumber']"
```

I need to implement ParseDefine function, but every line of powershell is always a pain form me...

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I think I came up with an alternate solution, that uses Powershell exclusively.

```
function readDefine {
    param([string]$name)
    
    $path = 'PATH/TO/HEADER/main.h'
    $header = Get-Content $path -Raw
    
    $header = $header | ForEach-Object {
        $ret = [regex]::Match($_, "(?<=\#\s*define\s*$name\s*)\w+")
        if ($ret.Success) { $out = $ret.Value }
        else { return $null }
    }
    
    return $out
}
```

This is called in the script as `readDefine EXAMPLE` and when your header contains `#define EXAMPLE 0x42` will return `0x42`. Should work for all types of defines, and is also whitespace insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I end up with partly C# in PowerShell solution, which was simplest for me:

```
$csharp = @"
 public class Reader
    {
        public static string ReadCDefine(string content, string key)
        {
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(content))
            {
                string lineT = line.Trim();
                string def = "#define " + key + " ";
                if (lineT.StartsWith(def))
                {
                    return line.Substring(def.Length).Trim();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
"@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition "$csharp"

$version = [Reader]::ReadCDefine("version.h", "VERSION")

$buildNumber =[string]::Concat($version,".", '%build.number%')

Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$buildNumber']"
```